# Calculating the (colloquial) likelihood of a result

Tags: probability, p-value, risk, credible-interval

A project that I am working on wants to use two factors to determine risk. First is an assessment by a subject matter expert (SME) on how much damage a calculated result would cause. Second is a quantification of how likely we think, or how confident we are in, the calculated result (probably in a colloquial sense, not the technical definitions of likelihood or confidence).

**Example**: I have two groups whose means differ by $7$ (feet, liters, chimpanzees, whatever...). If the SME deems $7$ to be of modest practical significance, then we might need modest likelihood to consider $7$ to be much of a risk. If the SME deems $7$ to be of trivial importance, then we might need certainty (if even that) to consider $7$ a risk. If the SME deems $7$ to be of extreme importance, then even a small risk might be a showstopper.

An idea that has been floated past me is using the p-value to quantify confidence. The probability of being at least as extreme as the test statistic is not exactly the probability that we want.

However, the p-value's sensitivity to sample size is appealing. If we have that difference of $7$, then I should be more confident that there is such a difference if I made $100$ observations than if I made $10$.

At the same time, if I have low confidence that $7$ is the right value, it could be because the real value is $9$, so low confidence in a measurement doesn't necessarily mean low probability of a large difference.

**QUESTIONS**

1. What would be a reasonable way to calculate this colloquial "confidence" or "likelihood"?
2. Can we get both the confidence and the impact in one number? Something like credible interval overlap with a region of practical equivalence seems to get at this, though I am not sure that it goes all the way. (We would have SME input on what defines a region of practical equivalence. Maybe do some kind of region of practical equivalence, region of modest impact, and region of catastrophic impact, then combine those results?)